# How to register event handlers for TypeScript declarations

Tags: javascript, typescript, bing-maps

I've asked this question on typescript's codeplex forums but didn't get an answer so I'm asking here. For a given TypeScript class declaration, for example the Bing Maps one (https://bingmapsts.codeplex.com/) how would someone register an event handler?

On the Map class (in Microsoft.Maps.d.ts) there are a couple of events declared:

```
viewchange: () => any;
viewchangeend: () => any;
viewchangestart: () => any;
```

And I've tried hooking a function like the following inside a typescript file but it never gets called:

```
///<reference path="Bing/Microsoft.Maps.All.d.ts" />

window.onload = function()
{
    var map = new Microsoft.Maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'),
        {
            backgroundColor: 0,                
        });

    map.click = () => alert('click');
    map.viewchangestart = () => alert('viewchangestart');
}
```

In traditional javascript, I would use the following:

```
Microsoft.Maps.Events.addHandler(map, 'viewchangestart', function (e)
    {
        alert('viewchangestart');
    });
```

but there is no such method in the typescript declaration and since I can't seem to reference the virtual earth map control from a .ts file I'm not sure how I can do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The definition (https://bingmapsts.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#BingTS.Solution/BingTS/Bing/Microsoft.Maps.d.ts)  is wrong : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg427609.aspx Those functions do not exist. You can only register events via the addHandler. Simple definition:

```
declare module Microsoft.Maps.Events{
    function addHandler(map:Microsoft.Maps.Map,event:string,func:Function);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's very likely the .d.ts file is simply wrong. They are usually hand-authored and should not be considered authoritative. I don't see any reference to a `viewchangestart` event object in the options parameter in the API reference, so whoever was writing that file probably just misread the documentation.

In terms of statement- or expression-level code, whatever you would have written in JavaScript, you should write in TypeScript. There's not any difference in terms of how external APIs are used.

Comment: I've corrected the code, the click and viewchangestart are not part of the options parameter as you pointed out, my bad. This still does not work however.